# Load a resource before HTML page renders

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm building a lightweight website, client-side only. I'd like to create some common components, like the nav-bar, that are shared across all pages. I can load these components with ajax and insert them where I want them, and tweak them to the specific page. The problem is that the page will often load before these resources do, meaning the nav-bar pops up a second too late.

My question: is there any way to require a browser to load an external resource (e.g. HTML) before the page displays, in the same way it loads .css and .js files immediately?

(Alternately, if you know of an alternate js-only way to reuse HTML components, that would work too.)

Thanks!

Comment: As a simple workaround, simply hide the pages complete content and unhide it after your navbar is loaded. You can simply use a promise/callback function

Comment: Thanks michael - I figured I could use that as a fallback, but I was hoping (I don't think unreasonably) that there would be a better way.